# Scaling scrollview only in three directions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, cgaffinetransformscale

I am making a sample project. I am having a scroll view which contains multiple views (At the top is a `UIImageView` with frame `CGPoint = 0,0` containing an image).

I want to implement the following feature:

When ever I scroll down, if the content offset of the scrollview becomes less than 0.0f and I keep on scrolling down, I want to zoom/scale the visible contents of the scroll view towards all sides except upwards.

I am currently scaling the scroll view with proper scale ratio. But, the issue is that the scroll view is being scaled in all the directions. I want to restrict this scaling only towards left, right and downwards (i.e. content should not move towards upwards).

Kindly suggest how can I implement the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[[yourView layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f)];
```

to change anchor position to center point of upper view edge, then scale.

Comment: FYI, the anchor point's coordinates are within range of `[0.f; 1.f]`.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please elaborate your answer with terms of the view/view structure i have mentioned in the question? Because i had tried manipulating the anchor point but it din't work for me.